# Postgresql function for passing arguments dynamically

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, procedural

I created a function abcd_insert() which inserts data into table abcd, which has 8 columns. The code inside the function looks similar to below :

```
BEGIN  
 INSERT INTO abcd

 VALUES 
      (
    x                 ,
    y                 ,
    select sum(count) from (select count(*) from a where a1 = x and a2 = y and a3 = 1 union all select count(*) from b where b1 = x and b2 = y and b3 = 1 ) as n1,
    select sum(count) from (select count(*) from a where a1 = x and a2 = y and a2 = 2 union all select count(*) from b where b1 = x and b2 = y and b3 = 2 ) as n2 ,
    select sum(count) from (select count(*) from a where a1 = x and a2 = y and a2 = 3 union all select count(*) from b where b1 = x and b2 = y and b3 = 3 ) as n3 ,
    select sum(count) from (select count(*) from a where a1 = x and a2 = y and a2 = 4 union all select count(*) from b where b1 = x and b2 = y and b3 = 4 ) as n4 ,
    select sum(count) from (select count(*) from a where a1 = x and a2 = y and a2 = 5 union all select count(*) from b where b1 = x and b2 = y and b3 = 5 ) as n5 ,
    SELECT sum(q1) from
    (SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(1) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as q1 FROM p1 where p11 = x and p12 = y union all
    SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(1) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as q1 FROM p2 where p21 = x and p22 = y )  as q1
  ); 
END;
```

'x' and 'y' are my input parameters whose values will be passed to the function abcd_insert(). a,b,p1 and p2 are tables within the same schema.
When I pass 'x' and 'y' to the function at run time, it throws error.
Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: function definition required to say what's wrong

Comment: @VaoTsun : Function definition is mentioned above. I wrote error is thrown when values are passed at runtime. Instead, I am unable to create the function itself. It says, "syntax error at or near 'select'"

Comment: When asking for help with an error message, it's important to include the *full text* of the error you're getting; it may include details which, while not helpful to you, provide a vital clue for someone helping you. It's also a good idea to include enough code to actually reproduce the error - in this case, you are missing the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement, and the example call to the function, leaving us to guess, and maybe guess wrong. This is known as providing a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better to specify the column names in your insert statement.

```
Insert into abcd ("column1",...,"column8") values ...
```

And please post the error, so that others can help.

Comment: If at all, identifiers need to be enclosed in double quotes. Single quotes are for string constants. `'column1'` is not a valid column name in SQL

Comment: Pardon me. I wrote error is thrown when values are passed at runtime. Instead, I am unable to create the function itself. It says, "syntax error at or near 'select'".

Answer (score 0):

with your sample code, you need brackets around queries, so you would use their result, eg:

```
t=# create table t (i int, e int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# create or replace function f(x int) returns void as $$
begin
 insert into t values (x, (select 1 where x > 0));
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
t=# select f(1);
 f
---

(1 row)

t=# select * from t;
 i | e
---+---
 1 | 1
(1 row)
```